# parsing/splitting data in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I send 6 data from sensors with header and tail, with (,) between the data

```
$data0,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5%.
```

I want to parse/sorting this data and become:

```
y0=data0
y1=data1...
```

How to do it?  I use Visual studio C++ 2010.

my program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
  {
string str = "$data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6%";
string word;
stringstream stream(str);
while( getline(stream, word, ',') )
cout << word << "\n";
 }
```

the value
is

```
$data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6%
```

how to erase header and tail, and how to make the data in the buffer

```
Y1=data1
y2=data2
 ...
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. If you're new to programming then http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ will give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code shows how it can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string s("$data0,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5%");

    s.erase(0, 1); // Remove header.
    s.erase(s.size() - 1, 1); // Remove tail.

    // Parse tokens.
    std::vector<std::string> tokens; // Vector will store tokens.
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    for (std::string token; std::getline(iss, token, ',');) {
        tokens.push_back(token);
    }

    // Output tokens.
    for (const auto& t : tokens) {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
data0
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
```

Comment: @Limavolt if you have exactly 6 entries, you can do `std::string y0 = tokens[0];` and so on